# Server Mainboard and Storage System

Tags: ubuntu, storage, devices

Does anybody know how the following storage devices will be supported by Ubuntu, Debian or Linux in generall??

- SATA-Controller: AMD SP5100
- SAS-Controller: LSI 1068E

Because I will buy the http://www.tyan.com/product_SKU_spec.aspx?ProductType=MB&pid=665&SKU=600000194 for my company, as a server mainboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some Googling around for "linux LSI 1068E" gives me a few links that say you'll have trouble with it.  Reference: [SAS disks on LSI 1068e not detected with 8.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-973912.html) [Supermicro X8DT3′s onboard LSI controller in Linux](http://www.thegibson.org/blog/archives/500) and [sassy lip from the lsi 1068e](http://blogaristoo.lqx.net/index.php/sassy-lip-from-the-lsi-1068e)

However, this suggests that support is recent, but exists: [LSI 1068E (including LSI SAS 3442E-R and LSI 3081E-R) instabilities](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/605939)

I'd suggest going with something else if you have the choice.